# Photoshop CS6 - How to duplicate pen tool path then transform it

Tags: adobe-photoshop, cs6, pen-tool, transform

I was wondering if it was possible to make a copy of a pen tool line, duplicate it then rotate that duplicate pen tool line 180 degrees, then again 60 degrees. After which I join both pen tool lines together make a selection then fill it in with a colour.

This is so I can make a segment the same as the Google chrome logo.

Here is an image below of what I currently have so you have an idea. You can see I've marked out the angles via the thicker line segments so it's just a case of drawing in the pen line paths, then I can fill it with colour.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would personally use Illustrator for precise measurements then paste them in Photoshop, but if you must use Photoshop only... You can easily use the tooltip while drawing a line with the line tool for precise measurements. The image provided shows you the tooltip with the line tool. If the tooltip with the measurements isn't showing, I'm not sure if it's a view that has to be turned on.

*added edit* You can then use the align functions to center the line vectors after selecting the lines.

[image: Tootip for measurments]

Comment: I did try this already it marked out everything perfectly but I used a polygon lasso tool to place a single highlight over these lines but it didn't end up fitting each segment very accurately. Is there a way you can join these lines up to form a segment that can be filled with colour? In other words a single selection. Rather than dragging a lasso tool over each line.

Answer (score 1):

You can copy by selecting the path via "Direct selection Tool" the one under the type tool, copy (CTRL + C) and then before pasting rotate the whole image, by going to image > image rotation > any angle you want, and the paste the path (CTRL + V).

Answer (score 0):

at least in PhotoShop CS4, you can duplicate a segment path but you can't transform it if such path don't cover an area or pixel. that is, a straigh line of two nodes can't be transformed. instead, you would use a line of one pixel thick so you can rotate it using transform command.

using the **Path Selection** tool (black pointer), select the shape and make sure **Show Bounding Box** is checked in the **Option Toolbar**. you might need to zoom in very close to the center of line until you see the crosshair mark. while pressing Alt/Option key, drag the crosshair to any position, then you can release key. this essentially duplicate a shape while you transform it. the same is true if you use any of the special anchors for transformation. finally, after positioning the crosshair in desired place, you would type the desired rotation degree in the **Option Toolbar**.